# How should I create a word-embedding an NLP model recognizing HTML elements?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language-processing

I'm currently doing a small-time project where I have to deliver a model which can classify specific elements on a web-page using the HTML code.

For this, I have considered using the HTML tags for each specific element (which I can extract using some other code) and then transforming it to a vector to give a neural network made to classify whether or not it is a certain element (text box, discount code field, question sheet, etc).

**My problem** is this: I cannot find any pre-made library of word embeddings for HTML elements and I know that training one using methods such as GloVe or RNN's can be rather cumbersome and require much data and processing, kind of outside the scope of the project itself.

**My question** is whether or not a word2vec algorithm already exists for vectorizing HTML elements alreayd exists, or if I need to make it from scratch. Or, whether there is an entirely different ML approach to classifying a wide range of different, possibly changing HTML elements based on their tags.

Thanks a ton in advance!